# Liquid Numeric Sort

Tags: string, sorting, integer, liquid, capture

I am trying to sort an array from small to large in liquid. Currently the output is [100, 2000, 250, 500]. I read that when using capture its creating a string and that you should try to convert it to an integer to sort it. Thats what I am trying down in the code with the tips from StackOverflow, but it seems that its not working. Whatever I am multiplying, its not doing anything. Can someone help me out?

The wanted result is
[100, 250, 500, 2000]

I have the following code:

```
{%- capture filtertitel -%}
 {%- for product in collection.products -%}
  {%- for variant in product.variants -%}
   {{- variant.title -}},
{%- endfor -%}{%- endfor -%}{%- endcapture -%} 

{%- assign unique = filtertitel | downcase | remove: " ml" | remove: "." | split: ","-%}
{% assign num = unique  | Times: 1 %}
{% assign num2 = num  | uniq | sort %}
                          
{%- for item in num2-%}
 <option value="{{- item -}}">{{- item -}} </option>
  {% endfor %}
```

I habe updated the code to the following. Its now converting to a number. I have checked this, because I can add 1 now. But still the output is in the same array. Output is now: [101, 2001, 251, 501]

```
{%- capture filtertitel -%}
{%- for product in collection.products -%}
{%- for variant in product.variants -%}
{%- assign varianttitel = variant.title | downcase | remove: " ml" | remove: "."-%}
{%- assign varianttitel = varianttitel | plus: 1 -%}
                              
{{ varianttitel }},
{%- endfor -%}
{%- endfor -%}{%- endcapture -%} {%- assign unique = filtertitel | split: "," -%}
                         
                          
{% assign num2 = unique  | uniq | sort %}
{%- for item in num2-%}
 <option value="{{- item -}}">{{- item -}} </option>
  {% endfor %}
```

Comment: You can't (as far as I know) convert a string array into a number array. You have two options: 1) Somehow start from a number array. For example using metafields. This is not always possible. 2) Use javascript. As ugly as it is, it's the only way I've found.

Comment: @FabioFilippi Hi Fabio, I have updated the code. Its still not working correctly, but its converted to a number now